# Can I change the region on my American Nintendo 2dsxl to European region

Tags: region-lock, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I have an American 2dsxl but European games won’t play. Is it possible to change the region?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just install homebrew!
It breaks the region lock, so you can play your EU games.
I recommend you follow a tutorial at https://3ds.hacks.guide

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. If you felt this answer is correct, click the checkmark by the votes.

Answer (score -2):

Select the System Settings icon on the HOME Menu, and tap Open.
Tap Other Settings.
Tap Profile.
Tap Region Settings.
Select the country and tap OK.
Select the region and tap OK to return to the profile menu.

Your Welcome.

Comment: Thats not how you change a region lock! You still won't be able to play other games!